# Setting and using ivars or passed parameters in setter functions

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter, ivar

I know this sounds like a really silly and stupid question but is there any difference in using the target ivars or the passed parameters when making extended setter functions like in:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString)text {
    _text = text;
    self.label.text = text; // VS
    self.label.text = _text;
}
```

Is there any functionality or efficiency difference between the two assignments for `self.label.text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference between using the ivar and the passed parameter in your example.

However, there is a difference if you use the accessor:

```
// These are the same
self.label.text = text;
self.label.text = _text;

// This will call the getter
self.label.text = self.text
```

As an illustration of the difference, consider if we had a custom (silly) getter:

```
- (NSString *)text
{
    return @"Hello";
}
```

In this case, the literal string `@"Hello"` would be returned regardless of the value of `text`.

Comment: seems to me like Apple could optimize on efficiency if they allowed for releasing of the passed parameter immediately after assignment.... but that's just a farfetched idea on my part

Comment: @Savagewood: If you mean have the method release its argument, that isn't in line with the standard memory management rules. If you mean you should be able to release an object after passing it to a setter, that normally is fine so long as the setter is strong or copy.